# run a git commit inside bash script for loop for multiple repos

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to write a script to make my bulk - git collaboration easier, to push / pull / or commit multiple git projects at once.

I work on multiple sites, and I want to pull all of the current changes for all of the sites at once.

Here is what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

REPOS=(
/Users/me/repo1
/Users/me/repo2
/Users/me/repo3
) 

echo push, pull or commit?

read input

if [$input -eq "commit"]
then
    for i in “${REPOS[@]}”
    do
        cd $i
        git add . -A
        git commit -m "auto commit backup point"
        echo "Moving to Next REPO...
         "
        sleep 2
    done 

else 
for i in “${REPOS[@]}”
do
    cd $i
    git $input 
    echo "Moving to Next REPO...
     "
    sleep 2
    done 
fi
```

Now, when the script prompts me for input, push or pull is working fine (sort of), the script runs through all of sites and pulls or pushes accordingly.

However when I respond "`commit`" the script goes through each repo, but the commits are not working properly. The Commit message prompt opens in vi which is not preferred, and the commit doesnt place. If I navigate to any of the repos there are still staged changes.

any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: thank you! I've never heard of this.

Comment: Additionally replace all `“` and `”` by `"`.

Comment: thanks, must've been a copy / paste from browser issue.

Comment: Use: 'bash -n script.sh ' to check  syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if [$input -eq "commit"]` has missing space. Rewrite it as `if [ $input -eq "commit" ]`. Otherwise it goes to `else` condition and does `git $input`, where input=commit.

Oh, yes, `-eq` is for integers, should be  `if [ $input = "commit" ]`.

Comment: @RobBenz Please check your script with  shellcheck.net as Cyrus recommended, it's not only potential problem.